# What's the correct RESTful behaviour of a PUT method with an auto generated ID in URL if the resource does not exist?

Tags: rest, put

I'm designing a REST API for a CRUD application. Resource ID's are UUIDs that are generated by the database on insert. So when I make a PUT, let's say something like

```
PUT http://host/books/{database generated UUID}
```

with the data in the body and the `{database generated UUID}` does not exist, what's the right behaviour?

I can't just create the resource with this UUID, because UUIDs are assigned by the database.
I can't just create the resource with a new auto-generated UUID, because then the PUT is not idempotent anymore, because every subsequent PUT would create a new identical resource with a new auto-generated UUID.

So how to RESTful handle this case? Return a 404? 400? 422? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

[403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-403-forbidden)

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to fulfill it.

As with all Client Errors responses, the details that explain the nature of the problem, and how it can be resolved are copied into the response body (the representation of "the explanation of the error situation")

---

Hypothetically, you could just do the work (producing the correct database generated id), and then redirect the client to the correct resource ([301 Moved Permanently](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-301-moved-permanently) or [308 Permanent Redirect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-308-permanent-redirect)).

> If the origin server will not make the requested PUT state change to the target resource and instead wishes to have it applied to a different resource, such as when the resource has been moved to a different URI, then the origin server MUST send an appropriate 3xx (Redirection) response; the user agent MAY then make its own decision regarding whether or not to redirect the request. -- [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-put)

After all, they are *your* resources, you can create/remove/update them any time you like.

The potentially tricky bit is whether or not a *general purpose* HTTP client will be confused by the response.

If you go this route, your code changes should be accompanied by documentation that describes the research you did, the alternatives available, the tradeoffs involved, and so on (aka an "architectural decision record" or some reasonable equivalent).

If your analysis tells you that the benefits of taking this approach are small, then you should probably bias toward doing a more normal thing and returning a client error.